# Counterexample to when $v$ of a particle is parallel to a unit vector $c$, and $c$ is in the plane of the curve?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, solution-verification

I'm solving exercise $14.9.11$ from Tom Apostol's Calculus, which is to prove that if a particle moves along a curve in such a way that it's velocity vector $v$ makes a constant angle with a given unit vector $c$, and if the curve lies in a plane and if $c$ is in the plane of the curve, then to prove that either $a = 0$ or $a \times v = 0$.

I understand people managed to prove that as for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4068721/942378), but my problem is why is a curve $r(t) = (1, \cos{t}, \sin{t})$ and $c = (1, 0, 0)$ not a counterexample to that?

As far as I see, $v = (0, -\sin{t}, \cos{t}), vc = 0, a = (0, -\cos{t}, -\sin{t}), av=0$, so $a \ne 0$ and $a$ and $v$ are orthogonal to each other.

What am I missing this time?

Thanks!

---

Edit: why is $c$ on the plane?

Arbitrary 3 points of the curve are $A = r(0)=(1, 1, 0), B = r(\frac{\pi}{2})=(1, 0, 1), C = r(\pi)=(1, -1, 0)$. $AB = (0, 1, -1), AC = (0, 2, 0)$. The plane of the curve is $M = \{A + tAB + sAC | t,s \in R \}$. If we plug in $t=0, s=-\frac{1}{2}$, we get point $(1,1,0) + (0, -1, 0) = (1, 0, 0) = c$.

Comment: $c$ is not in the plane of the curve.

Comment: @GReyes sorry, but it's not clear to me why not? Can you please explain, because it seems like I'm missing something?

Comment: You are confusing "$c$ lies **in** the plane" with "the endpoint of $c$ is **on** the plane." In interpreting "$c$ lies in the plane," think about $c$ as an arrow from tail to tip $(0,0,0)$ to $(1,0,0)$. The tip of the arrow is on the plane, but the arrow is not within the plane, which is what Apostol means here.

Comment: Here, $c$ lying within the plane means that if we take a point $x$ in the plane and add $c$ to it, the resultant $x+c$ will also be in the plane. Here, $c$ is actually perpendicular to the plane.

Comment: Interesting, because usually he uses vector to represent just the point which always has the beginning at the $0$. How could I know in advance what he meant? :) Can you please add this as the answer, so I can close the question?

Comment: Ok, when he uses a capital letter for vector, then it's a vector starting from 0, but if it's a small letter, then it is an arbitrary vector.